Do there exist Noetherian groups which are not co-Hopfian?
A Noetherian group is a group for which every subgroup is finitely generated.
A group $G$ is called co-Hopfian if it is not isomorphic to a proper subgroup of itself; equivalently, every injective group homomorphism $\phi : G \to G$ is surjective and hence an isomorphism.
Noetherian groups are Hopfian (not isomorphic to a proper quotient). Must they also be co-Hopfian?

The group $\mathbb{Z}$ is not co-Hopfian since it is isomorphic to the subgroup $2\mathbb{Z}$ but is Noetherian (every subgroup is of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$).

Ah yes, thank you! Harder question: What if G is not co-Hopfian, with witness H of infinite index? (so Z no longer works, and I think such a group will have to be non-Abelian.)

@Queggers i thought a bit and i don't know. i think you should make a new question!
